# Android Webview : Cannot call JS function from Java Code

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have following webview with interface:

```
 public void setWebview() {
        try {
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.intro_browser);
            // Set Chrome instead of the standard WebView
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            mWebView.clearCache(true);
            mWebView.clearHistory();
            mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
            mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(), interfaceName);
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/my_access.html");
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:toBeCalledFromAndroid()");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TEST", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I am able to call Java native code via JS but i need to call also JS function via Java code to pass some data into webview.

So I tried to add:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:toBeCalledFromAndroid()");
```

After the static page content is loaded.

But it's not working:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/FixedColumns.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>


</head>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
function toBeCalledFromAndroid() {
        alert("TEST");
    }
```

How I should to update my code to pass data from Java to JS?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: First, try something like this: mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('called from JAVA');"); and look into logcat

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is following:**

I called my second `loadUrl()` way too soon, `loadUrl()` is asynchronous. So I need to wait until page is loaded.

Call `webView.loadUrl("javascript: toBeCalledFromAndroid('test')");` in the `OnPageFinished` method solved my problem.